# c# Download file from website to a path with whitespaces

Tags: c#, download, whitespace, webclient

I have this function :

```
public void DownloadFile(string urlAddress, string location)
    {
        using (webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);

            Uri URL = urlAddress.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? new Uri(urlAddress) : new Uri("http://" + urlAddress);

            sw.Start();
            try
            {
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

`DownloadFile(downloadUrl, path_to_up);` // path_to_up is from another method

The problem is that if path_to_up is something like : C:\Program Files(x86)\Test\Program Test\file.exe , it doesn't work. Works only for paths like D:\FolderWithoutSpaces\file.exe.

I tried :

- to add `@` before `path_to_up`
- to replace `\` with `\\`
- to write directly the dir , like `DownloadFile(downloadUrl, @"C:\Program Files(x86)\Test\Program Test\file.exe");`

Searched on google the whole night, but nothing helped me.
How can I solve this problem ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get an exception? Do you have permission to access that Program Files folder?

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with whitespace in folder names

Comment: No exception. I call the function from a button_click ... and i get "Download completed" . If the problem isn't related to whitespaces, then how can i download to a path like that ?

Comment: I've just created a folder with whitespaces in C:\ (C:\Test Test) and it works. So, why i can't download in program files(x86) ?

Comment: Run your program as Administrator! If it works, it is a rights issue.

Comment: It would be of a great help if you can provide the exception that was thrown. Saying that 'it doesn't work' thoes not help us does it?!

Comment: It doesn't work you say... what do you get ? an error/exception ? pls clarify.

Comment: Ok, looks like the problem is related to permission access. Tried with admin rights and it works. It's possible to get the permission to download there without opening the application with admin rights ? Or at least, make the application to ask user for permission before downloading ?

Comment: just curious. what is `sw.Start();`?

Comment: Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); for a progress bar .

Comment: Thank you , guys for helping me. The application that contains that download method is an updater ... so i start it from the main program, but before i start it, i added process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; .. and so i get the rights for the updater. Thanks again.